# A confusion about shortcut key of youcompleteme for vim

Tags: vim

all. I am trying to use youcompleteme for code completing in vim. Generally, it works well except that when i need to jump between source files. 
First. I use the subcommand

```
:YcmCompleter GoToDefinition
```

it can find the definition. BUT it seems so verbose. Then I want to map this subcommand into some shortcut key according to the YCM's instruction:

```
nnoremap <leader>gl :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gf :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gg :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
```

I am a little confused. what is short cut key? l or gl ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create a mapping with `<leader>`, `<leader>` is replaced by whatever is in your "mapleader" variable (by default `\`).

If you have this in your vimrc:

```
let mapleader=","
nnoremap <leader>gl :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
```

It acts the same as:

```
nnoremap ,gl :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
```

Thus you could run the `YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration` command by pressing <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can type `\gl` to go to the definition. The default `<leader>` is the key `\`. So if you type `\gl`, you can go to the definition.

And another shortcut you can try, Ctrl+o -> you can return back where you came from.